# matchparen made a wrong match on angle brackets

Tags: plugin-system

I used the `MatchParen` to match the parenthesis while coding C++ projects.

Here is my config in `.vimrc`:

```
hi MatchParen cterm=underline ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=DarkCyan
set matchpairs+=<:>
```

However, it doesn't work very well when `cout` and `cin` appear together. Here is an example:
[image]

As you see, the two angle brackets are matched, which is not what we expected.

Is there some way or some vim-plugin to avoid this?

Comment: There are other similar cases, as `<`, `>`, `<<`, `>>`, `<=`, `>=` are valid operators in c++, my suggestion is to let it go, as long as it doesn't bother you when you deal with template parameters.